# Find all points on the helix at which $r$ and $r′$ are orthogonal.

Tags: calculus, vectors

> Consider the helix $r(t) =\langle \cos t,\, \sin t,\, t\rangle$, for $\:- \infty < t < \infty$. Find all points on the helix at which $r$ and $r'$ are orthogonal.

What steps do you take in finding the points on the helix at which $r$ and $r'$ are orthogonal?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please show us your work and at what points you are having problems! I've given a fairly complete answer, please try to finish it or explain other difficulties

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to ask yourself what it orthogonality means. Also, we need to compute $r_t$
\begin{equation}
r_t = (-\sin{t}, \cos{t}, 1)
\end{equation}
Do you know when two vectors are orthogonal? If not, it means that the inner product $\langle r_t, r \rangle$ is equal to $0$. Or 
\begin{equation}
\langle r_t, r \rangle = -\sin{t}\cos{t} + \sin{t}\cos{t} + t = 0
\end{equation}
Which you will need to solve, which should be easy! Then, I think you should be able to finish the exercise now :)